# Which cable needed to connect cable modem to D-Link router?

Tags: router, cable-modem

Below are pics of the cable modem and DLink router

Immediately below, is a pic of the back of my cable modem.

[image]

Below is a pic of the back of new D-Link router

[image]

Could you please inform which cable to use to connect router and modem together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Cat5 ethernet cable between the "Ethernet" port on the back of the Cable Modem to the "Internet" port on the router.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Was confused of the USB port.

Comment: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Tnx DavidPostill

Answer (score 0):

This one.
[image]

Plug the Cat5 ethernet cable into the "ethernet" port of the modem and the plug the other end into the "internet" port of the router.

I don't know what you would plug into the USB port, though.

Comment: I know you can't read it from the image but I suspect the label on the back of the modem is "ethernet" not "internet"

Comment: Yes, it is ethernet

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question—yes, a standard Ethernet cable between the modem and router would work—but none have really addressed the issue of the USB port shown in your original posts question past [5pike](https://superuser.com/a/822465/167207)’s answer that simply states:

> I don't know what you would plug into the USB port, though.

I know exactly what would be plugged into the USB port: A standard USB cable!

The deal is with many modems—DSL modems and cable modems—they allow you to connect your modem directly computer via a USB cable. This is an option provided for users who simple want their system’s OS to directly communicate with the modem and and use it for connectivity. This has utterly nothing to do with Ethernet capability that most of us are familiar with, but is a separate connection provided as an option for end users.

So unless you want to connect your modem to your PC directly via a USB cable, you never have to worry about the USB port on the modem. Heck, if you want to connect your modem to your PC directly you can easily use that same Ethernet cable if you wish.

But one other benefit of having a USB port like that on a networking device is to be able to easily—and stably—flash the firmware on the device via a USB connection. Many devices allow firmware flashing to happen via the Ethernet connection, but others *only* allow firmware flashing to happen via a direct serial or USB connection.